# Unique character for components(separatedBy:) in swift

Tags: swift, special-characters

I have a var like

```
var myStr = "\(bar)\(foo)"
```

`bar` is a dynamic text which I will get on runtime (It may contain any character)

`foo` is just a static string(in predefined list). Means, I know its text value

How can I separate `bar` and `foo` using `components(separatedBy:)` method? If I keep a char like *space, comma, etc* between these strings, there is possibility to get a wrong `bar` value if the bar string contains the *space, comma, etc*.

Is there any special character to separate the strings safely?

**Note**: The `foo` string is an optional one. It may or may not present. If the `foo` string is out of my set of static strings, I will throw an error.

Comment: If foo is always know, you want drop the first (with `dropFirst(_:)`?) letters equivalent to `bar`., and put the rest into an array?

Comment: Or keep them in a tuple, `(String, String?)`, until you need to use them as one string

Comment: Foo is always known but it is an optional. If it is not available, the dropFirst() will fail incase the bar has the dropping character. Although other proposals like tuples can solve the scenario, I cant use them. I need a String type var :(

Comment: You could use some magic number (or character in this case) but it's not a very good solution since you never know if that character could somehow be used in `bar`. Strange that you can't use a tuple since you want to separate them, I mean you could make `myStr` into a computed property that converts the tuple to a string for instance.

Comment: I would use a struct with "foo" and "bar" properties and a computed property as well or a throwing method if you need to throw an error

Comment: My first comment mixed variables name, but I meant if `bar` is always known, then `var components: [String] = []; components.append(bar); components.append(String(myStr.dropFirst(bar.count)))`. Also, why not use a tuple as said? Or a custom struct? You'd make `myStr` a computed var, and would be able to retrieve directly `foo` if needed.